# Multilevel enumerate inside tabularly environment generates incorrect numbering

Tags: tables, lists, enumerate

I'm trying to include  a `enumerate` list in an `tabularly` environment, but the numbering gets wrong when I add more than one level of depth to the list.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\setlength{\tymax}{0.8\linewidth}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}LL@{}}
Wrong row&
\begin{enumerate}
\item First.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Second
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}\\
\end{tabulary}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

This code generates the following output for the row:

```
Wrong row 
           1   1.1 First
                   1.1 Second
```

If i add another nested level the output gets messy with overlapping numbers.

Outside of any table, enumerate is being working fine thorught all my document.

EDIT:

I have simplified the example to the maximum and I could make it work, think it was the column type, which now is set to P.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|Lp{10cm}|}
    row1&value\\
    row2&
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Second
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which now generates the correct output:

```
row1     value
row2     1. First
            1.2 Second
```

Comment: Can you turn this into a complete compilable example? Your code as it stands doesn't compile.

Comment: No, make this a *complete* compilable document (with `\documentclass{}\usepackage{}...\begin{document}...\end{document}`.  Don't post fragments.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm new to Latex world. I have corrected the second example and  it is working now for me. The problem with first was the column type.

Comment: So have you effectively solved your problem? If so, perhaps we should close the question as too localized.  (BTW, your sample document *still* doesn't compile: you haven't defined the `L` columntype or loaded a package which defines it.)  Since you're new, this is one thing you definitely need to get used to.  People will be very happy to help you, but you should almost always post complete, compilable documents that show your problem.  Sometimes just the process of making one can help you solve things yourself.  See [this question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/2693) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of the code fragments that you posted compile however the basic issue is that `tabulary` enables display math but not other display environments in `L` columns. A small patch fixes this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\makeatletter
\let\oldTYtab\TY@tab
\def\TY@tab{\expandafter\TY@xtab\oldTYtab}

\def\TY@xtab#1\bgroup{%
#1\bgroup
\let\list\@gobbletwo
\let\trivlist\relax
\let\endtrivlist\relax
\let\item\relax}

\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\setlength{\tymax}{0.8\linewidth}
\small
\noindent
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}LL@{}}
Wrong row&
\begin{enumerate}\item First.
\begin{enumerate}\item Second\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{tabulary}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```